# How come I can't redirect TCP ports on this wireless router?

Tags: ip, router, port-forwarding

I am configuring a router to redirect TCP port 5900 (yes, this is for VNC) to a specific IP address on the network. Here is what I have:

[image]

From a local computer on the same network, I can `telnet` to 192.168.1.64 (port 5900) just fine. **However**, when trying to `telnet` to the machine (port 5900) using its external IP address, it doesn't work. (The connection times out.)

The router is a Gigaset SE567, if that helps.

Comment: Also, I found this Mikrotik page to be pretty useful in understanding hairpin NAT... [Mikrotik Wiki - Hairpin NAT](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT)

Answer (score 7):

You're running into the hairpin NAT problem. The problem is the following:

1. Your client opens a connection to [externalIP]:5900
2. Your gateway converts the target address to [InternalIP]:5900
3. Your server on [internalIP] sees a connection from [InternalIP-2] and sends an ACK to [InternalIP-2]
4. Your client sees an ACK from [InternalIP-2] and not from [externalIP] like it was expecting, and drops it. No connection is ever established.

The gateway needs to be smart enough to translate internal *source addresses* to itself so it can handle the correct translations. Consumer routers generally don't support this operation. The usual method is to just use the internal IP when connecting internally, or use a split DNS configuration.

Comment: That's odd though... my home router does this just fine (translating internal addresses like you mention) so I didn't expect this type of problem. What's a split DNS configuration?

Comment: Also, is there a special name for this type of problem?

Comment: Your internal DNS server resolves myserver.example.com to 192.168.1.14 and your external DNS server resolves myserver.example.com to a real IP address.

Comment: @sys: Aha! More examination of the router options page reveals a NAT address configuration page with the following: "Network address translation (NAT) directly translates an IP address from your home network to an address on the Internet. It only allows one machine from the home network to access the Internet." (Which is of course not an option.)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Yes, the term for this problem is called NAT Hairpinning, named after the 'hairpin turn' the packet makes at your border router.

Comment: @sys: When you describe split DNS, I'm a little confused... what is the internal DNS server? (I assume the external DNS server is the one configured in the router settings, currently 8.8.8.8)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Try connecting to your external IP from an external machine (instead of your local one) and see if it works. That will verify the problem.

Comment: @syb: The problem is there alright.