# Accessing web site/server from inside a NAT network

Tags: networking, nat, web

I've got a web server/file server running on a small network that is connected to the outside world via an ADSL line. Everything works great, but the problem we have is that we can't access the web site or server via the URL from inside the network, presumably due to NAT.

My question is: is there any way around this? I can use the HOST file to redirect the URL to an internal IP, but that's no good on the iOS devices we use. Is there perhaps something at the router level?

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come I can't redirect TCP ports on this wireless router?](http://serverfault.com/questions/252521/how-come-i-cant-redirect-tcp-ports-on-this-wireless-router)

Comment: Yes, poissibly there is something on a router level. Can you tell me where the fuel port is on my car? Please? Note: I dont tell you what car. How you expect us read the documentation of YOUR router (which is your job, btw., not ours) if you insist on even keeping the model secret? Maybe you should hire a borderline competent admin? One that knows how o read documentation and can ask quesiton giving the model number.

Comment: Ahh, I do enjoy self rightcheous IT people. Bet you're a joy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Many firewalls/routers do not allow routing back to an internal host, like you're trying to do when you're accessing your internal server on it's externally masqed IP.

Either get a firewall that has mechanics to help with these situations (A Cisco ASA can use DNS spoofing for example), or use hosts/internal DNS server to masq the hostname(s).